# Array has two elements; array.length returns 20

Tags: java, arrays

I have an array of `BufferedImage`'s. In the example breakpoint the array contains two elements. Anyway the length property returns the value of 20. How is that even possible?

[image: eclipse debugger]

Comment: Show actual code instead of Eclipse's debug view.

Comment: @asteri No, show both please

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That seems like an IDE setting. It will only show the non-null elements in the array in debug view. Eclipse does this.

Comment: Thanks. That was the issue.